# How is foot-pounds of energy defined?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, history, measurement, unit-systems

Tom Lodgson's classic textbook [Orbital Mechanics: Theory and Applications](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0471146366) frequently measures energy in foot-pounds, which I'd always thought to measure torque.  The book doesn't define it.  Is it the archaic foot pound-force [sic], or the gravitational potential energy of one pound hoisted one foot in a constant gravitational field, or something else?  (Is this unit still in use in aerospace or in other fields?)

Comment: It's certainly true that the same set of units can describe multiple situations.  Take a look at, e.g., some of the tables of constants in the NIST standard SP811

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it... the gravitational potential energy of one pound hoisted one foot in a constant gravitational field...?

Yes indeed it is!

To be energy, the pound has to be parallel to the foot.

$$E = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{s}$$

To be torque, the pound has to be perpendicular to the foot

$$\tau = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F}$$

1 foot-pound (or pound foot) of energy is 9.81 (m/s^2) / 2.2 (kgf/lb) / 3.3 (ft/m) = 1.35 Joules.

Comment: @RussellBorogove in physics they are, and have to be, the same thing. The order can not matter, so I'm forced to pound my foot and stick to my principles.

Comment: The last line here emphasizes that my two guesses for the unit's meaning are equivalent.  Bingo!

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune good guess! I've added a reference to your question. For the value, I used 9.81 m/s^2 but I assume if you use a [standard gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity) $g_0$ of 9.80665 m/s^2 and whatever the exact conversion from feet to meters is, you'll get Wikipedia's 1.355818 Joules

Comment: Delightful pun... and the unwashed rabble (of which I must thus be a member) also use lb-ft and ft-lb interchangeably.

Comment: Re, "parallel,"..."perpendicular",...  That description somewhat masks the truth. To be energy, the object to which the pound of force is applied must _move_ one foot in the direction of the force.  To be torque, nothing needs to move, but the pound of force must be applied to a point that is one foot away from the axis of rotation, and the radius and the axis and the force all must be mutually perpendicular.

Comment: @SolomonSlow **I disagree!** with your characterization of my answer; that is exactly what I wrote; there is movement in the 1st equation (integral over distance) and *no movement* in the 2nd equation, where the pound is perpendicular to the foot. My description *states the truth*.

Comment: One is (not necessarily) linear force applied for some distance, and the other is torsional force applied at a distance. A mention of work performed in applying force against a load/brake in an arc would be interesting.

Comment: Yet another reason why engineers and scientists use the SI system, so as to avoid ambiguity like this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units

Comment: @uhoh, I don't understand. Your reply to my comment says, "...exactly what I wrote; there is _movement_..." But the word "movement" does not appear anywhere in your answer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow this is an integral of movement along a path that is 1 foot long. See [Path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral) or [Line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) $$E = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{s}$$

Comment: I guess that would be obvious to a physicist. Maybe not so obvious to somebody who is struggling to understand how torque and energy can appear to be specified with the same units (i.e., to the guy who asked the original question.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow the author of the question would leave a comment asking for clarification if they were unsatisfied with the answer. Instead they have clicked "accept" so I have to assume they are satisfied. They have the same units because they simply do. There's no reason whatsoever that they couldn't have the same units. I think if you would like a better explanation than mine, then the best thing to do would be to ask a follow-up question in [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) rather than Space Exploration.

Comment: @SolomonSlow In your question be sure to include a link to my current answer and explain why it's unsatisfactory or not helpful for you, and what you'd like to see explained further, or in more detail. This is Space Exploration SE and so while we use Physics and talk about it a lot, a pure Physics question would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

Foot-pound or pound-foot are synonymous, and represent the arithmetic product of pound (force) and foot (length).

The pound (force) is the weight of one pound (mass) at the Earth's surface (somewhat imprecise because Earth's gravity field varies depending on your location, and the effective weight of an object will be influenced by the centrifugal force due to Earth's rotation, again dependent on location).

As a unit of energy, it is the energy of applying a one pound force over a distance of one foot. It is equivalent to raising a one-pound mass one foot in height, well... because.

As a unit of torque, it is the torque resulting from a one pound tangent force applied at a distance of one foot from the axis of rotation.

The same could be said of the Newton-meter (or meter-Newton, but it's never expressed that way); as a unit of energy, it is a one Newton force applied over a distance of one meter; as a unit of torque, it is a one Newton tangent force applied at a distance of one meter from the axis of rotation, except that the Newton is specifically a unit of force with a precise definition where pound may be either force or mass and pound (force) lacks a precise definition.

The measurement system which includes pounds and feet has a long history. When it developed, the variability of Earth's gravitational field and its impact on the weights and measures which depended on it wasn't understood, wasn't measurable, and/or wasn't significant for the engineering problems of the time. Culture, history, and familiarity keep these weights and measures in use despite the awkwardness and the advantages of metric.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot-pound_(energy)) foot-pound and foot-pound-force are synonymous:

> The foot pound-force (symbol: ft⋅lbf or ft⋅lb) is a unit of work or energy in the Engineering and Gravitational Systems in United States customary and imperial units of measure. It is the energy transferred upon applying a force of one pound-force (lbf) through a linear displacement of one foot.

It’s equal to 1.356 Joules.

The torque unit is the pound-foot, not foot-pound.

Comment: But pound-foot is used for torques too.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken about lb-ft vs ft-lb. I'll also admit that wikipedia's claim ft-lbf = ft-lb was true thirty years ago when Tom started lecturing.  Let's see what others report...

Comment: Per @uhoh's answer, for both energy and torque, when you decompose the mathematical shorthand in the integral and the cross product, you wind up with the units being a force times a distance. Multiplication is commutative, so force times distance is equivalent to distance times force. Distinction between pound-foot and foot-pound isn't physics, it's semantics.